# Group By Days Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Não estou conseguindo agrupar dados por dias diferentes.
Tenho alguns comunicados cadastrados e com o padrão Created_at e Updated_at
gostaria de mostrar esses comunicados Separados dia a dia..
**VIEW**

```
@foreach($messages as $message)
        <li class="time-label">
        <span class="bg-red">
            {{  $message->updated_at }}
        </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> </span>

                <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#"></a> ...</h3>

                <div class="timeline-body">
                    {{ $message->message }}
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
```

**TENTATIVA DE AGRUPAR POR DIA CONTROLLER**

```
public function timeline(Request $request){
    $messages = Message::where('type_send', 1)->groupBy(function($date){
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('D');
    });

    return view('messages.timeline', compact('messages'));
}
```

**NÃO ESTA FUNCIONANDO ERRO**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT CONTROLLER**

```
public function timeline(Request $request){
    $messages = Message::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()
        ->groupBy(function($date) {
            return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('M d'); // grouping by day
        });
    return view('messages.timeline', compact('messages'));
}
```

**DUMP EM $messages NA VIEW**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria agora de listar as mensagens separadas por mes, qual seria a solução?

**VIEW**
**Eu consegui mostrar o dia do mês, mas agora eu quero listar dentro as mensagens com o mesmo dia do mês**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ul class="timeline">
    @foreach($messages as $message)
        <li class="time-label">
        <span class="bg-red">

            {{  $message->first()->updated_at }}
        </span>
        </li>
                <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>
                    <div class="timeline-item">
                        <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> </span>
                        <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#"></a></h3>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
    @endforeach

</ul>
```

Comment: Então, o erro é o seguinte: ele espera um parâmetro texto (ou múltipla colunas separadas por virgula), o que você fez não é suportado Se quer agrupar por dia a estratégia tem que ser outra porque do jeito que você também fez está faltando algumas coisas nessa SQL (builder)

Comment: eu estou o dia todo tentando fazer isso e não consigo, o que eu deveria alterar?

Comment: Qual é a SQL que precisa fazer?

Comment: da uma olhada no edit @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Vamos explicar o que você fez, trouxe um massa de dados em `SQL` e depois na classe `Collection` agrupou os dados, ou seja, teve dois esforço (talvez só com a SQL já daria certo). você quer agrupar por mês? ou mês e Ano? eu ainda estou na duvida o que realmente quer, se poderia colocar um exemplo atual da sua base e o qual resultado espera?

Comment: Eu quero listar todas as mensagens separadas por dia do mês, mostrar uma vez o dia do mês e todas mensagens desse dia do mês. conforme o outro edit meu com o resultado da visualização, se você reparar @VirgilioNovic no dia Mar 21 eu tenho 6 mensagens e no dia Mar 22 eu tenho 1 mensagens

Comment: Então me parece que tem o resultado só não consegue imprimir? na sua View está como? ou não fez nada lá?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Minha view esta como o print que eu te mostrei, apenas consegui colocar os dias do mês que tem mensagens, mas não conseguir por as mensagens dentro, teria de usar um foreach dentro de outro foreach? Olha o Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisa buscar a chave e depois a coleção da respectiva chave:

```
@foreach($messages as $key => $message) 
    <li class="time-label">
    <span class="bg-red">
        {{  $key }}
    </span>
    </li>
    @foreach($message as $item)
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-envelope bg-blue"></i>
            <div class="timeline-item">
                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> </span>

                <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#"></a> ...</h3>

                <div class="timeline-body">
                    {{ $item->message }}
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-footer">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

isso é mediante ao seus comentários.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou, o que seria a $key?

Comment: `$key` é a chave do seu `array` precisa dela para imprimir o cabeçalho e dentro dela que tem o `collection` que precisa utilizar no seu código. @GabrielAlves